# Include one character with two digit value

Tags: c, pic, mplab

The code below show, to check the digital output at PORTB on the hardware. That PORTB have UI1-UI12.
When it is not shorted, the value will be 1.

So if nothing shorted, when i write UI5-UI7 in Hyperterminal it will show 0x03 (111bit in binary)

Here the code:

```
void decode(unsigned char* msg) {

    AD1PCFGL = 0xFFFF; //set all analog pin to digital
    int y, z, x;
    unsigned char* lala[50];

    if (strstr(msg, "UI") == msg) {//UI[2]-UI[6]

            x = msg[2] - '0'; // char to integer
            y = msg[6] - '0'; // char to integer

            //UI[2]-UI[6]
            int start = x - 1; //get offset, start from zero  
            int end = y; // end
            int pinValue; // each pin value
            int output_value=0; // result
            int j = 0, i; // j, start from 0

            for (i = start; i < end; i++) {
                pinValue = ((PORTB & (1 << i)) > 0 )?1:0; // get current pin value from RB3, RB4, RB5, RB6, RB7->UI4, UI5, UI6, UI7, UI8
                output_value |= (pinValue << j++);
            }
            sprintf(lala, "0x%X \r\n", output_value); //%02x(hex),%X(HEX) 
            sendString(lala);// send to Hyper-Terminal

        }
}
```

How to include msg[2] and msg[6] with two digits number ?
Because, from the above code, there was problem when i write UI10-UI12, it give the wrong result.

Comment: For some specific input, what result do you actually get, and what result do you expect?

Comment: `UI1-UI10 = 0x3FF` ... `UI5-UI7 = 0x03` ... `UI5-UI5 = 0x1` ... `UI10-UI12 = 0x03` ...

Comment: i guess there is problem with declaration at `msg[6]` , i try to add `msg [7]` , but it will poblem when `msg[7]` not used. Same goes to `msg[3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input is always in the same format, it's simple to use e.g. [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to split the input into the two parts, and then use [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to convert the numbers to integers.

Something like this perhaps:

```
char *start_string = strtok(msg, "-");
char *end_string = strtok(NULL, "-");

int start = strtol(start_string + 2, NULL, 10);
int end = strtol(end_string + 2, NULL, 10);
```